# What am I doing wrong when calculating similarity according to Pearson correlation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, correlation

Given the following formula, I need to calculate how similar two vectors are.
$$s(i, j) =
\frac { ri ⋅ rj } {∥ri
∥2∥rj
∥2}$$

my vectors:

$$ri = [1,3, 5,5, 4] $$
$$rj  = [2,4,2,3,4,3,5] $$

I started to solve the problem by calculating the numerator as follows:
$$ (1x2) + (3x4) + (5x2) +(5x3) + (4x4) + (3) + (5)  =$$
$$ 2 + 12 +10 + 15 +16 + 3+5 = 63 $$

So now I need to calculate the denominator. So I started by calculating the magnitude of the vectors as follwos:
$$r1$$
$$ ∥ri∥ = (1)^2 + (3)^2 + (5)^2 + (5)^2 + (4)^2    $$
$$ ∥ri∥ = 1  + 9 + 25 + 25 + 16 = {\sqrt{76}} = 8,71  $$
$$rj$$
$$ ∥rj∥ = (2)^2 + (4)^2 + (2)^2 + (3)^2 + (4)^2 + (3)^2 + (5)^2   $$
$$ ∥rj∥ = 4  + 16 + 4 + 9 + 16  + 9 + 25=  {\sqrt{83}} = 9,11 $$

So, now I already have:

$$s(i, j) =
\frac {63 } {(8,71) 2 (9,11) 2}$$

$$s(i, j) =
\frac {63 } {17,42 . 18,22}  = 0,1984 $$

**My professor said the answer is 0.41.** However, as you can see, I can get a result of 0.19. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help? Also, I can't quite figure out what these 2s in the denominator mean. Do I need to multiply them?

Comment: Why do your two vectors have different numbers of elements? Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Comment: Also, whatever you did to format the formulas, it almost worked, but not quite. You can fix it by editing the question. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Also, what you are trying to compute looks more like cosine similarity than Pearson correlation coefficient to me. Maybe another reason to take a look if you copied everything correctly